# Fail surefire when a test is ignored

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have the following setup: maven-surefire-plugin + junit5.

Now I'm doing some preparations in the @BeforeAll in order to connect to a database. But in some situations the setup is not working properly. In that case an exception is thrown. Now surefire marks the test as ignored. But an ignored test does not make the build fail.

I already tried the org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException and org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError, but that had no effect. I found no configuration and also no proper documentation about that.

Has anybody an idea how to handle that properly? I just want that the tests fail in case the setup is not working properly.

Comment: Which exception is thrown in your setUp method? Could you add the stacktrace?

Comment: In the end this doesn't matter. It's an derived from a RuntimeException. In this case it's a DriverException from the cassandra driver.